# Import C enum into python without including full header?

Tags: python, c, enums, swig

Is there an easy way to expose enumerated constants defined in a C header file to Python using SWIG, but without using `%include "header.h"` to SWIG the entire header? In other words, I'm writing my SWIG interface manually because I do not want to auto-generate python bindings for everything. However, there are enums defined in the header file that I would like to make available to the Python side. My files look like this:

**foo.h**

```
typedef enum fooEnumType {
    CAT, DOG, HORSE
} fooEnum;
```

**foo.i**

```
%module foo
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}
```

And in `foo.i`, I can access `CAT` in my C code. Of course, `CAT`, `DOG`, and `HORSE` are not available on the Python side. How do I expose them to Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the portions you want from `foo.h` in the `foo.i` file instead of `%include "foo.h"` that processes everything:

**foo.i**

```
%module foo
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

typedef enum fooEnumType {
    CAT, DOG, HORSE
} fooEnum;
```

**foo.h**

```
typedef enum fooEnumType {
    CAT, DOG, HORSE
} fooEnum;

typedef enum otherEnumType {
    A, B, C
} otherEnum;
```

Output:

```
>>> import foo
>>> dir(foo)
['CAT', 'DOG', 'HORSE', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '_
_spec__', '__warningregistry__', '_foo', '_newclass', '_object', '_swig_getattr', '_swig_property', '_swig_repr', '_swig
_setattr', '_swig_setattr_nondynamic']
```

Note that CAT/DOG/HORSE are defined but A/B/C are not.  `swig -python foo.i` generated the wrapper with no errors.

Comment: I had tried that, but because the typedef is already defined in foo.h, I get a redefinition error. Even if I don't `%include "foo.h"` on the swig side, I still must `#include "foo.h"` on the c side.

Comment: @Fadecomic Adding that declaration as shown above doesn't redefine `fooEnum`.  It tells SWIG to generate a wrapper for the declaration.  If you are getting a redefinition, you actually are defining it twice on the C side.  I'll updated my answer with a proof.  If you are still getting an error, create a [mcve] like I did in my answer that reproduces the problem.